# Angular2 Observers

Tags: typescript, angular

I am currently trying to set observers to three different fields in my application, where when, each field updates, the other two update accordingly. Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ControlGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder } from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'temperature-form',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <form [ngFormModel]="temperatureForm">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">°C</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Celsius" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" [ngFormControl]="celsiusField" [(ngModel)]="celsius">
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">°F</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fahrenheit" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" [ngFormControl]="fahrenheitField" [(ngModel)]="fahrenheit">
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">K</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kelvin" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" [ngFormControl]="kelvinField" [(ngModel)]="kelvin">
            </div>
        </form>
    `
})
export class TemperatureForm {
    temperatureForm: ControlGroup;

    celsius: number;
    fahrenheit: number;
    kelvin: number;

    celsiusField: AbstractControl;
    fahrenheitField: AbstractControl;
    kelvinField: AbstractControl;

    constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.temperatureForm = formBuilder.group({
            'celsiusField': [''],
            'fahrenheitField': [''],
            'kelvinField': ['']
        });

        this.celsiusField = this.temperatureForm.controls['celsiusField'];
        this.fahrenheitField = this.temperatureForm.controls['fahrenheitField'];
        this.kelvinField = this.temperatureForm.controls['kelvinField'];

        this.celsiusField.valueChanges.subscribe(
            (value: number) => {
                this.fahrenheit = this.celsiusToFahrenheit(value);
                this.kelvin = this.celsiusToKelvin(value);
            }
        );

        this.fahrenheitField.valueChanges.subscribe(
            (value: number) => {
                this.celsius = this.fahrenheitToCelsius(value);
                this.kelvin = this.fahrenheitToKelvin(value);
            }
        );

        this.kelvinField.valueChanges.subscribe(
            (value: number) => {
                this.celsius = this.kelvinToCelsius(value);
                this.fahrenheit = this.kelvinToFahrenheit(value);
            }
        );
    }

    celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius: number): number {
        var fahrenheit: number;

        fahrenheit = celsius * (9 / 5) + 32;

        return fahrenheit;
    }

    celsiusToKelvin(celsius: number): number {
        var kelvin: number;

        kelvin = celsius + 273.15;

        return kelvin;
    }

    fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit: number): number {
        var celsius: number;

        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);

        return celsius;
    }

    fahrenheitToKelvin(fahrenheit: number): number {
        var kelvin: number;

        kelvin = this.celsiusToKelvin(this.fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit));

        return kelvin;
    }

    kelvinToCelsius(kelvin: number): number {
        var celsius: number;

        celsius = kelvin - 273.15;

        return celsius;
    }

    kelvinToFahrenheit(kelvin: number): number {
        var fahrenheit: number;

        fahrenheit = this.celsiusToFahrenheit(this.kelvinToCelsius(kelvin));

        return fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

However, the problem is, the UI continuously updates fields, and the values change like crazy. Is there any way to fix that? I think it starts automatically because of default value. But, when I update a field, the other fields are updated, but also, valueChange event is fired for them, and this goes on infinitely. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division creates doubles and doubles shouldn't be compared using `==` or `===` at all, but Angular doesn't care. Therefore you need to take care of this yourself.

```
    this.celsiusField.valueChanges.subscribe(
        (value: number) => {
            var farenheit = this.celsiusToFahrenheit(value);
            if(Math.abs(farentheit - this.farenheit) > 0.0001) {
              this.fahrenheit = farenheit;
            }
            var kelvin = this.celsiusToKelvin(value);
            if(Math.abs(kelvin - this.kelvin) > 0.0001) {
              this.kelvin = kelvin;
            }
        }
    );
```

similar in the other functions.

This way you stop the updates when the difference is below `0.0001` (adjust according to your requirements).

Note: You might need additional null checks.

Comment: I do know about validation, but for now, I am only testing with valid data. It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: I am afraid not. I do not know how.

Comment: Let me upload to github.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't use the value passed by `valueChanges`. Just use it as an event to recalculate but use the values from the class fields instead `this.fahrenheit`, .... When events callbacks are processed values might be passed that are already stale because another event recalculated them. See https://plnkr.co/edit/a1suKyDQlXouMrXpKarK?p=preview. The other changes I made might not be necessary.